# Does Angular 5 support Angular material latest version(7)

Tags: angular-material, angular5, angular-material-7

I need to use the latest version of Angular material i.e version 7.x. But my current Angular version is 5.x. is it possible to update Angular material alone?

Comment: I strongly doubt that Angular Material 7.x will work on Angular 5.x, but you can try it by updating the material and cdk packages.

Comment: Material has peer dependency on angular core, common and some other angular  packages. Therefore you wont be able to update to material 7.x without updating Angular 5.x

Comment: yes Murgin you are correct

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command that updates Angular Material/CDK to the latest version:

```bash
ng update @angular/material
```

See the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after analysis, I understood we can't update angular material to version 7.x in Angular 5 project. Angular project need to be updated to 7 to have angular material 7.x